# Group data in table by 2nd column while consolidating values in 3rd column

Tags: list-manipulation

I currently have a list in the format:

```
 {Group, State, num}

{{a, CA, .5},
 {a, AK, .2},
 {a, MX, .1},
 {b, CA, .8},
 {b, AK, .8},
 {b, MX, .1},
 {b, HI, .7}}
```

I would like to ignore the first (`Group`) entry and form a list whose elements contain the `State` followed by all the associated `num` values, yielding, for instance:

```
State // Group1 # // Group2 # 

{{CA, .5, .8},
 {AK, .2, .8}, 
 {MX, .1, .1},
 {HI, 0, .7}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *assumes* your "group" names and "state" names are all unique..
( aside, I'd prefer to use strings for the state and group names, but this does work )

```
 l = {{a, CA, .5}, {a, AK, .2}, {a, MX, .1}, {b, CA, .8}, {b, 
       AK, .8}, {b, MX, .1}, {b, HI, .7}};
 gpton = Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1 -> First@#2} &, Union[l[[All, 1]]] ], 1];
 ston = Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1 -> First@#2} &, Union[l[[All, 2]]] ], 1];
 (m = SparseArray[Join[ {#[[2]], 1} -> #[[1]] & /@ ston,
      Map[  {#[[2]], #[[1]] + 1 } -> #[[3]]  &, l /. gpton /. ston]]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since this looked to me a lot like an operation on a dataset, I thought -- just for fun -- I'd try that approach. This will be a step-by-step presentation because there is no way I can write this kind of code in a single unreadable expression, such as are often admired in our community.

Raw data to data set.

```
keys = {"grp", "state", "num"};
vals = 
  {{a, "CA", .5}, {a, "AK", .2}, {a, "MX", .1}, {b, "CA", .8}, 
   {b, "AK", .8}, {b, "MX", .1}, {b, "HI", .7}};
ds1 = Dataset[AssociationThread @@@ (Rule[keys, #] & /@ vals)]
```

[image: ds1]

Regularize the records to make processing easy. Items in the "num" column are wrapped by `List` so `Catenate` can be applied later. The missing "HI" record is appended. The dataset is sorted by "state". (What state does "MX" represent?)

```
ds2 = Append[
        ds1[All, {"num" -> List}], 
        AssociationThread[keys -> {a, "HI", {0.}}]] // SortBy[Key["state"]]
```

[image: ds2]

Reduce the dataset to what is wanted

```
ds3 = ds2[GroupBy["state"], Catenate, "num"]
```

[image: ds3]

Munge the transformed dataset into the list form requested.

```
byState = (ds3 // Normal // Normal) /. Rule[x_, {y_, z_}] :> {x, y, z}
```

> ```
> {{"AK", 0.2, 0.8}, {"CA", 0.5, 0.8}, {"HI", 0., 0.7}, {"MX", 0.1, 0.1}}
> ```

Comment: You read my mind but I got stuck on the munging.

Comment: I'm having trouble creating variable ds3. I get a two column dataset with state[<|<<1>>|>] in each row for the first column. Also looks like a ds4 is used but not initialized

Comment: @krieger_saan. My apologies. There was a typo in my answer. There is no `ds4`. I have corrected the definition of `byState` to use `ds3`, not `ds4`.

Comment: @m_goldberg Looks like my other problem was with the ds3 = ds2[GroupBy["state"], Catenate, "num"]-- example works when changed to ds2[GroupBy[**Key[**"state"**]**]]

Answer (score 0):

```
l = {{a, CA, .5}, {a, AK, .2}, {a, MX, .1}, {b, CA, .8}, {b,AK, .8}, {b, MX, .1}, {b, HI, .7}};
mx = Max@(Length /@ Gather[l[[;; , 2]]]);
dd = Merge[Dataset[Rule @@@ l[[;; , 2 ;;]]], Identity];
Flatten /@ (List @@@ Normal[Normal[dd[;; , (PadLeft[#, mx, 0] &)]]])

(* {{CA, 0.5, 0.8}, {AK, 0.2, 0.8}, {MX, 0.1, 0.1}, {HI, 0, 0.7}}*)
```

Based on your comment, here is one way of doing it:

```
l = {{a, CA, .5}, {a, AK, .2}, {a, MX, .1}, {b, CA, .8}, {b, 
    AK, .8}, {b, MX, .1}, {b, HI, .7}, {c, HI, .7}};
l2 = Flatten[
   Thread[List[#, Union@l[[;; , 2]], 0]] & /@ Union@l[[;; , 1]], 1];
l3 = SortBy[DeleteDuplicates[Join[l, l2], #[[;; 2]] === #2[[;; 2]] &],First];
dd = Merge[Dataset[Rule @@@ l3[[;; , 2 ;;]]], Identity];
Flatten /@ (List @@@ Normal[Normal[dd]])
(*{{AK, 0.2, 0.8, 0}, {CA, 0.5, 0.8, 0}, {HI, 0, 0.7, 0.7}, {MX, 0.1,0.1, 0}}*)
```

Comment: I tried this on my non-abstracted dataset, and I found that the col order does not keep. For example in the above, if you change the HI group spec to 'a' it will not move from the right col. Any pointers for a fix?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your comment but if you mean that the result should be sorted according to the first column then you can do that from the beginning l=SortBy[yourlist, First].

Comment: Please note this code works with any number of columns and also works on duplicate entries

Comment: When the declaration for {b, HI, .7} changes to {a, HI, .7}- the result of {HI, 0, 0.7} should swap to {HI, 0.7, 0}. Apologies for not being clear

Comment: @krieger_saan see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Just for giggles:

```
l = {{a, CA, .5}, {a, AK, .2}, {a, MX, .1}, {b, CA, .8},
     {b, AK, .8}, {b, MX, .1}, {b, HI, .7}};

Total /@ GatherBy[Replace[l, {{a, x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0}, {b, x_, y_} :> {x, 0, y}}, {1}],
                  First] /. Times[_, b_] :> b

(* {{CA, 0.5, 0.8}, {AK, 0.2, 0.8}, {MX, 0.1, 0.1}, {HI, 0, 0.7}} *)
```